# Is it possible using the Docker remote API to copy an image to another host?

Tags: docker

Supposed I have two servers, let's call them `A` and `B`. Both run Docker as daemon, and I have created an image on `A`.

So, of course, I am able to run this image as a container on host `A`.

Supposed I want to move that image to `B` - how do I do this? Is this possible via Docker's remote API? Or by any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you can use `docker save`, `scp`, then `docker load`.
Alternatively, you can `docker push` then `docker pull`.

If you are not confortable using the public index, you can spawn a private registry. Take a look at https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry. The easiest way to do so is `docker run stackbrew/registry`. You will have more details on the github readme.

Comment: Didn't know about `save` and `load`, but actually they solve what I need to do. Thanks for pointing them out :-)!